# How can I be sure my power plane can pass required current, considering width, via numbers, and PCB layers transition?

Tags: power, current, pcb-design, pcb-layers

In my 8-layer stackup, I have power plane in layer 6 that should carry up to 5A.
The thing is, I can't have a continuous plane and I need to move to layer 8 (bottom) to make connect between the two planes as the following:
[image]

[image]

My internal layers have 1.2 mil copper thickness, and the external layers has 1.6 mil:

[image]

According to [4PCB](https://www.4pcb.com/) calculator, for external layers, I need a plane width of 93.8 mil, mine is 100 mil. the question is, can I count on this calculation?:

[image]
In case I didn't have 100 mil, does increasing vias number help for passing current?

**Update**: I moved some signals and and I could use another connection (300 mil width) for the plane in layer 6 (1.2 oz), where by using same calculator, the width in internal layers must be 325 mil, but as it's another addition to the 100 mil I already have on an outer layer, I think on overall, I'm OK now:
[image]

Comment: Try another calculator and see how the results compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of the calculator should be reasonable. You could compare it to another one to double check, e.g. the [Saturn PCB Toolkit](https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/) is relatively popular.

Note that in the Optional Inputs, temperature rise is set to 10°C. I would consider a setting of 20°C to still be ok.

Vias will not really help much with the current your power planes can carry. But vias themselves have limits in how much current they can carry. The Saturn PCB Toolkit can assist you with calculations too. As a rough design rule of thumb I keep a maximum of 1 A per standard via in my head. The calculator will probably give you a slightly higher number. The 4 via connection to the right plane in your first picture could use a via or two more for 5 A.